# Know which user created div was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I apologise if my explanation is hard to understand.
Using This Code:

```
names.push(newName);
var strName = newName;
var newName = document.createElement('p')
newName.setAttribute('id', newName);
document.body.appendChild(newName);
newName.innerText = strName;
$(newName).css('position','absolute')
$(newName).css('top', y);
$(newName).css('left', x);
updateXY();
```

The user creates a new div (with a user-inputted name) which works fine.
my problem is that i don't know how to know when one of these user-crated-and-named divs is clicked.

For example:

if the user created 2 divs, 'hello' and 'goodbye' i couldnt just use $('#hello').click(function() {}); etc. Because i wouldnt know that the user would've chose to create the div entitled 'hello'

Furthermore, the array names has all of the names of all of the divs in - if this is any help to anybody. Thankyou, and any help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you create this divs with a prefix, like "userCreated" so you know that all the divs with that start with that name/id belong to user created ones?

Comment: Why don't use add common class to all divs and add `$(document).on('click', 'common-class', function() { });`

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the event listener to the element as you did when styling it:

```
 $(newName).on("click",function(){
   console.log("element "+$(this).text()+" clicked");
 });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xt3hnu3/)

Or, with JS's [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener):

```
newName.addEventListener("click",function(){});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tgqmfkb/)

Or, the old way for older browsers, [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):

```
newName.onclick = function(){};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/539s6mkL/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
$(newName).on("click",function(e){
    // the variable 'e' is the event of click, if we do e.toElement, we get to know who the element clicked is
    var $thisDiv = $(e.toElement);
    // do something with $thisDiv
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create a div element, you need to initialize 'click' event on the div

```
<a class="js-create-div" href="#">Create Div</a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function init(){
      var newUserDiv = $(".js-user-div").not(".js-inited");

      newUserDiv.on("click",function(){

        alert($(this).html());

      });

      newUserDiv.addClass("js-inited");
    }

    $(".js-create-div").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").append("<div class='js-user-div'>"+Math.random()+"</div>");        
    init();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ema0nazs/